# variable arrangement in vs2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, gcc, compiler-construction

Code://VS2010

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;

int main(){
    //output the address of global variables
    printf("0x%x, 0x%x, 0x%x, 0x%x\n", &a, &b, &c, &d);

    int a1, b1, c1, d1;
    //output the address of local variables
    printf("0x%x, 0x%x, 0x%x, 0x%x\n", &a1, &b1, &c1, &d1);

    int a2 = 1;
    int b2 = 2; int c2; int d2 = 4;
    //output the address of local variables
    printf("0x%x, 0x%x, 0x%x, 0x%x\n", &a2, &b2, &c2, &d2);
}
```

Output:

```
0x1197a44, 0x1197a3c, 0x1197a40, 0x1197a38
0x15fb00, 0x15faf4, 0x15fae8, 0x15fadc
0x15fad0, 0x15fac4, 0x15fab8, 0x15faac
```

My Question:

1. `Why are the global variables not stored in order`? The above output represents that they are out-of-order.
2. `Why are the local varialbes not stored continuously`? The above output represents that VS2010 inserts 8byte space between every two of them.

Does anybody can help me? Thanks very much!

---------------------------------------complement------------------------------------------

Code:\gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;

void main(){
        //output the address of global variables
    printf("%p, %p, %p, %p\n", &a, &b, &c, &d);

    int a1, b1, c1, d1;
        //output the address of local variables
    printf("%p, %p, %p, %p\n", &a1, &b1, &c1, &d1);

    int a2 = 1;
    int b2 = 2; int c2; int d2 = 4;
        //output the address of local variables
    printf("%p, %p, %p, %p\n", &a2, &b2, &c2, &d2);
}
```

Output:

```
0x60103c, 0x601034, 0x601038, 0x601030
0x7fff126253a0, 0x7fff126253a4, 0x7fff126253a8, 0x7fff126253ac
0x7fff126253b0, 0x7fff126253b4, 0x7fff126253b8, 0x7fff126253bc
```

---

In gcc, the address of global variable and local variable is continuous and in-order.

So I want to know what and why the vs2010 does that for our code.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of them is specified by the specification, the compiler can do what it want to do.

As to the local variables, you are probably using the `DEBUG` build, and the padding is inserted to check stack integrity. If any memory overrun happens, the padding would be overwritten and the overrun would be spotted.

Comment: My wildest guess would be that the compiler uses something like a hash of the variable name. That hash is sorted, but that does not corresponding to the order in which you define your variables. Plus, you should not rely on that order anyway (unless you write assembly code...) If you need things in order, create a structure or an array.

Comment: Thanks Alexis! I know what you mean, but I want to know what and why VS2010 do these for our code.

Comment: A hash would be used for better speed instead of searching arrays from top to bottom. This being said, they could make use of an extra index table... Now without looking inside the code, it would be hard to tell the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has undefined behaviour, because the types specified in the format string do not match the types of the other arguments passed to the `printf`.

As such, your code does not demonstrate that the variables are not stored continuously.

Comment: Yeah - try printf( "%p", &a );

Comment: Although it is true that he should use %p, that's not why the variables are not continuous!?

Comment: @AlexisWilke: Why do you say the variables are not continuous? Daneill's code has not demonstrated that at all. All that it has shown is that programs with undefined behaviour sometimes have unexpected results.

Comment: I use printf("%p", &a) to have a try. The output is the same.

Comment: I guess I should have written that variables do not need to be allocated in a continuous manner (one after the other.) Although the size of the variable can make it look like it's not continuous because of padding. For local variables, it may also reuse the same location multiple times (once a variable lifetime is over, another can reuse its location safely) and local variables are often allocated in registers (except if you dereference them as in the example.)